# React - how to use the lifecycle methods

Tags: reactjs

I keep encountering the same problem with React. I feel I should be using the lifecycle methods. (Other than just componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps). But they never seem to meet my purpose. Here are 2 examples:

1. Asynchronous loading

My parent component loads some data with AJAX. A grandchild component needs this data - which is passed down via props. Because of the timing the data may be available when the child component is mounted or not. I don't know whether to put the code in my grandchild component which depends on these props in componentWillMount() or in componentWillReceiveProps(). I end up having to put it in both. (Or in a method they both call).

2. Lifecycle methods are either called on the initial render or not. I want them to be called on both.

My component gets some data. (Using getStateFromFlux - a mixin provided by Fluxxor). This occurs several times during the cycle of loading the data with various flags set onto the retrieved data object: unloaded, loading and loaded let's say. This change of state causes a re-render.

I only want to render and show the data if there is something to show. So - my render method has the first line:

```
if data.loadState != 'loaded'
  return '<span />'
```

Ok. Well. I thought - there must be a lifecycle method to fix this. So I've done this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function (nextProps, nextState) {
    if nextState.loadState == 'loaded'
      return true
    else
      return false //stops the render. Good. 
}
```

At last I thought - I have used a lifecycle method.

But, alas, while this does stop the render being called in some cases - when  there is no data - I still can't remove the hacky looking line about

```
if data.loadState != 'loaded'
  return '<span />'
```

This is because shouldComponentUpdate is *not called for the initial render*. When this component first renders there is no data. loadState is 'unloaded'. The render method is still called. And I still need to avoid displaying the UI (with empty data fields).

In general terms - the lifecyle methods are either called only on the initial render or only on subsequent renders. For most of my uses cases this is singularly unhelpful. I want a method which is agnostic to whether it is the first render or a subsequent one.

What am I missing about React? (The only thing I can think of is is that it is designed to be used with an initial render server-side when you can be sure of your data - then once in the browser the lifecycle methods are about detecting changes).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you should be using the lifecycle methods, they're awesome and let you hook into your components in a much more in depth way. But I don't think this is the case for your current situation

1. You could just conditionally render the grandchild only when the data is loaded by the parent and passed to the child.  Then you'd only need the check in the child.  It would look something like this:

   ```jsx
   // Child render method that has been passed data loaded by the parent
   render: function() {
     var grandChild = null;
     if (this.props.data) {
       grandchild = <GrandChild data={this.props.data} />
     }
     return (
       <div>
         {grandchild}
       </div>
     )
   }
   ```

In this case, you only pass a `data` prop to the child component once the data has loaded.  Thus, you're guaranteed that when the grandchild component does render, it will have the data that it needs. Although I'm not sure why you are so averse to displaying empty data fields, this should solve the problem.

2. You're correct, there is no React lifecycle method that fires regardless of whether it's the initial render or not.  That being said, if you have to do both, you can always a combination of `componentDidMount` and either `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps`.  I'm not 100% sure why they did this, but a couple reasons that come to mind:

   - Ensures that React will not need to re-render a component before the initial render (ie. changing state in `componentWillReceiveProps`, triggering an update before the initial render).  I'm not too familiar with the code-base, but I can easily see that causing problems.
   - Performance boost for the initial render to let your content load faster while the virtual DOM is initialized

I hope this helps solve your problem and sheds some light on the lifecycle methods!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about loading but with unloading I would suggest;

```js
if (this.props.data.loadstate == 'unloaded') return null;
```

Have that as the first line of the render. As you noted shouldComponentUpdate only applies to updates.